# Key tool is location is not identifying by Ansible

Tags: ansible

I want to import a certificate to hosts.i have written playbook for that.keytool is there in *usr/java/jdk/bin/keytool* location but following error is coming.
I have converted below this two commands in to playbook but $JAVA_HOME is unable to find by playbook.

$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -import -alias Apple_Corporate_Root_CA -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -trustcacerts -file apple_corporate_root_ca.pem

$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -import -alias Apple_Corporate_Root_CA_2 -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -trustcacerts -file apple_corporate_root_ca2.pem

```
playbook:

    ---
- hosts: test
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
      pack1: /ngs/app/rdrt
      pack2: /usr/java/jdk*
      pack3: which_keytool.stdout
      pack4:  !vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          39646535636262343133633334366538356361356430613566643162316438366266626135323737
          6633316430653038316330653437343535346266356265650a343262643938363631656237326331
          31363961323839626533363739623639656662336361633131373765333563333034393963373737
          6439663362333164660a313432666333306463616562346564323139303364343539623335373931
          6537

  tasks:
    - name: copy the files
      copy:
         src: "/Users/sivarami.rc/Downloads/Problem46218229/apple_corporate_root_ca.pem"
         dest: "{{ pack1 }}"

    - name: copy the files
      copy:
         src: "/Users/sivarami.rc/Downloads/Problem46218229/apple_corporate_root_ca2.pem"
         dest: "{{ pack1 }}"

    - name: copy the files
      copy:
         src: "/Users/sivarami.rc/Downloads/Problem46218229/ca-trust-check-1.0.0.jar"
         dest: "{{ pack1 }}"

    - name: to register the value of keytool
      shell: cd /usr/java/jdk*/bin/|ls|which keytool
      register: which_keytool.stdout

    - name: Import SSL certificate to a given cacerts keystore
      java_cert:
         cert_path: "{{ pack1 }}/apple_corporate_root_ca.pem"
         cert_alias: Apple_Corporate_Root_CA
         cert_port: 443
         keystore_path: "{{ pack2 }}/jre/lib/security/cacerts"
         keystore_pass: "{{ pack4 }}"
         executable: "{{ pack3  }}"
         state: present

    - name: Import SSL certificate to a cacerts keystore
      java_cert:
         cert_path: "{{ pack1 }}/apple_corporate_root_ca2.pem"
         cert_alias: Apple_Corporate_Root_CA2
         cert_port: 443
         keystore_path: "{{ pack2 }}/jre/lib/security/cacerts"
         keystore_pass: "{{ pack4 }}"
         executable: "{{ pack3 }}"
         state: present

    - name: checking those files trusted or untrusted
      shell: "{{ pack2 }}/bin/java -jar {{ pack1 }}/ca-trust-check-1.0.0.jar"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I indented your error message by 4 spaces with <!-- language: none --> so that it renders properly - please see [the editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of misunderstanding you have with ansible, as well as file paths goin on here.

First,

```
  pack2: /usr/java/jdk**
```

is strictly speaking not *wrong* but is also not doing to do what you expect. Foremost, having two stars does not make it "more wild". A single `*` is sufficient for having the shell match arbitrary globs.

What *is* wrong is your use of `{{ pack2 }}` verbatim in a lot of the subsequent modules, but we'll get to that in a second.

Next,

```
      pack3: which_keytool.stdout
```

will not do what you want, because ansible does not have the ability to evaluate expressions, so `{{ pack3 }}` will forever be the characters `w` `h` `i` and so forth. It will never be `{{ which_keytool.stdout }}`

Next,

```
  shell: cd /usr/java/jdk**/bin/|ls|which keytool
```

is some very bizarre and highly incorrect shell script. I think perhaps you meant:

```
shell: /bin/ls -1 {{ pack2 }}/bin/keytool
```

in order to have your shell expand the `**` and then try and match a `bin/keytool` child.

In your circumstance, you'd actually be better off matching that jdk directory earlier in your playbook, and then assigning that to a `jdk_home` fact so that `{{ jdk_home }}/bin/keytool` would behave sanely, as would `keystore_path: "{{ pack2 }}/jre/lib/security/cacerts"`

---

Separately, those are terrible variable names. You are just causing heartache for "future you" or for your colleagues. No one has any prayer of remembering what `pack2` means.

Comment: can you give me example playbook.how to call a java_home variable in to the playbook.in the java_home location only the key tool is there.

Comment: how to change the execute shell sh to bash in the hosts.that I need to declare in the playbook.please help me out. am facing java_home path is not reading the playbook

Comment: I don't understand your questions. The way S.O. works is that you report the errors you are experiencing, along with the playbooks you are using, and the ansible-playbook command line you used, and we'll help you find the error. And do not, under any circumstances, put that information here in a comment; update your question with it.